# Linux Bash Script File Search for Log File

Tags: linux, bash, search, shell-script, bash-scripting

How would I go about writing a Linux bash script for the following?

I need to search for a file of format [unique_number].log
This file would exist within one of the following directories

```
/dir1/usr/home/var/log/logfile-20150504/[unique_number].log
/dir2/usr/home/var/log/logfile-20150504/[unique_number].log
/dir3/usr/home/var/log/logfile-20150504/[unique_number].log
```

I'd like to prompt the user for the date (for the logfile-20150504 part) and then prompt them for the log file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRS="dir1 dir2 dir3"

echo -n "Date (YYYYMMDD): "
read YMD
echo -n "Log name (unique number): "
read UQM
for D in $DIRS ; do
  LOG="/$D/usr/home/var/log/logfile-$YMD/$UQM.log"
  test -f "$LOG" && echo "Located file @ $LOG"
done
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! There was a slight syntax error where there should be a $ sign before UQM.log, but I figured it out. Much appreciated.